# Loop on function when creating an object Java

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface which has a function as shown below:

```
public interface Myinterface {
    Myobj1 getobjdata(int var1, int var2) throws IOException, SocketTimeoutException;
}


Myinterface mi = new Myinterface() {
    @Override
    public Myobj1 getobjdata(int x, int y) throws IOException, SocketTimeoutException {
        return c.getobjdata(x, y); //c is another class
    }
};
```

In Myinterface mi I wonder how I can loop on this overridden function so I can fill the mi with all the objects corresponding to it which has x ranging from 0 to 10 and same with y? Like where I can place the for loop where mi will be filled with 100 objects data.

I've tried the below but it gives an error saying "missing return statement , not sure why?

```
Myinterface mi = new Myinterface() {
    @Override
    public Myobj1 getobjdata(int x, int y) throws IOException, SocketTimeoutException {
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            return c.getobjdata(x, y); //c is another class

                    }
                }
            }

        };
```

**UPDATE**

following the suggested answer I tried it but then I add a print statement but it's never called, which means the code inside the function never runs, not sure why?

```
Myinterface mi = new Myinterface() {
    @Override
    public Myobj1 getobjdata(int x, int y) throws IOException, SocketTimeoutException {
         System.out.println("entered");
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                            return c.getobjdata(x, y); //c is another class
                    }
          }
          return null;
       }
    };
```

Comment: don't you think it's a kind of cycle in getobjdata method.

Comment: can you please post the definition of "Myclass" Interface.

Comment: @shivam edited the questions, sorry it's an interface not a class.

Comment: You are trying to return 100 times in the same method. Do you want to return one array that has all the 100 getobjdata return values in it or do you want to call getobjdata 100 times and use the result each time?

Comment: don't you think it's a kind of cycle in getobjdata method. when you will call MyInterface.getobjdata it will again call itself and it will continue untill stack overflow exception will come.

Comment: @JoeyHarwood it won't give the same results as the indexes are different

Comment: @shivam I need to fix the error first and see how it goes, any idea why it says "missing return statement"?

Comment: @Shepherd that exception is coming because you are returning Myobj11 inside for loop only  . you need to put one return statement outside of for loop

Comment: just consider sceanrio when control will not go inside of first for loop. I know control will go into first loop but at compile time ,compiler will not be knowing that.

Comment: If you never see the console output then your code is never calling mi.getobjdata(...). Also, why would you create two `for` loops whose variables you never use inside the loops?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from your above code, it just appears that you aren't calling the method `getobjdata()` on the `mi` field at all. Just declaring the `mi` field in a class with the `getobjdata()` isn't sufficient. You also need to actually call it from somewhere else. You need to find your code that is actually running and be sure to call `mi.getobjdata(x,y)` from there.

Answer (score -1):

you need to try this to avoid "missing return statement".

```
Myinterface mi = new Myinterface() {
    @Override
    public Myobj1 getobjdata(int x, int y) throws IOException, SocketTimeoutException {
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                            return getobjdata(i, j);
                    }
          }
          return null;
       }
    };
    int dummy1 = 1, dummy2 =2;
    mi.getobjdata(dummy1,dummy2); // now it will come into "getobjdata" function
```

As i already suggested you , you will get stack overflow exception as it's a kind of cyclic method call.

Comment: I've done that and added a print "test" just before the for loop but it never enters this getobjdata function, why?

Comment: @Shepherd just after this you have to call that function then only it will get executed and whatever you did is just a object declaration , creation and initialisaztion .

Comment: you had not called that function till now that's why it is not coming .